# Web application ".nuget" and "Application Insights"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-application-insights

I am trying to create a basic asp.net web application in visual studio 2013. Once I click create project I get the dialog box with messages showing the packages/nugets is loading. I then got a message that it's unable to load the Application Insights. I'm not sure what Application Insights is but I've never received that message before. Also there is a weird folder called ".nuget" that appears in my solution which i never had in previous web application solutions.

I know this could be something related to azure but i'm not sure how to remove it from my solution safely and what i should do in order not have them be loaded in newly created solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application Insights is a monitoring service that helps get telemetry about your application. To disable the option to add Application Insights to your project, uncheck the Application Insights box in the "File->New" dialog.